# DNS Setup with Azure and terraform - MX records non-functional

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, mx-record, terraform

How do you set up a Domain MX record on Azure with Terraform's azurerm provider?

When you set up an MX record, it is normal to make the name the FQDN "example.com." (at least with BIND).  Terraform/Azure however does not permit this naming.  And the example docs at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/dns_mx_record.html 
suggest using the name "test".
This is clearly stupid as it then creates a MX record for the subdomain test.example.com - which is NOT what you generally want at all.

For example:

```
resource "azurerm_dns_mx_record" "example-com-mx" {
  name = "mx"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.prod-rg.name
  zone_name = azurerm_dns_zone.example-com.name
  ttl = 300

  record {
    exchange = "ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM."
    preference = "5"
  }
  record {
    exchange = "ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM."
    preference = "5"
  }
  record {
    exchange = "ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM."
    preference = "10"
  }
  record {
    exchange = "ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM."
    preference = "10"
  }
  record {
    exchange = "verificationcodehere.mx-verification.google.com."
    preference = "15"
  }
}
```

works great if what you need a mail exchanger for mx.example.com! But not if you want a domain mail exchanger.

Comment: I thought I had it fixed, but turns out, not so much.  When I manually create it with a name of "@" it works, but if I terraform it with that name I get a subdomain with the name of "@.example.com".

Comment: looks like from the terraform docs.. you don't need to add the period at the end of the FQDN for the exhange's

Comment: @Mike turns out if you do that’s you get the expected result, mx.example.com.example.com,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out it’s a missing feature in the azure plugin, they have made a patch and looks like it’ll be in 1.40.0